# Black screen for 10 seconds after single beep on power on

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, graphics-card, motherboard

I've been dealing with this since ever since I've started to use my recently bought my Intel DH61CR mobo.

Immediately after powering on my PC, I hear a single loud beep, which lasts for about a second. Right after that my monitor keeps switching between analog and digital display (no display though, it just keeps going back and forth) for about 10 seconds prior to the "Intel logo" screen showing up along with the Boot Options (CMOS SETUP, BOOT MENU, ... standard stuff).

The OS boots and everything looks fine from there on out. The thing is, every so often, my hard drive "chokes" and everything stops responding, except, eventually, when the Task Manager feels like loading. Now the Windows doesn't crash or anything, it just keeps in a frozen-like state. Ever since it started doing this, I've tested my hard drive using some surface scan tools and even got to replace the motherboard for a brand new one. HD was spic and span, same effects with the new mobo.

For the last 2 days, I've tried removing my GeForce GT430 Video Card and my DVD-RW drive and, at least up until now, I haven't seen it happen again. Additionally, already tried updating BIOS, drivers, OS updates, etc. To be honest, after all that, my computer just seems as slow as ever. I haven't mentioned it before, but it REALLY IS terribly slow to 1155 standards. Even my Core 2 Duo E7600 seems to be doing a better job.

What frustrates me the most about these problems is that both of them occur intermittently, and I'm unable to track what is the root of it. I'm beginning to consider that somehow both are connected.

Specs :

- CPU: Intel Core i5-2310 @2.90GHz
- RAM: 2x 2GB DDR3 PC3-10700
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GT430 PCI-e 16x
- HDD: ST3500.418AS 500GB SATA3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single beep typically means *System Memory Issues* (check http://brebru.com/beepcodes.html or google 'single beep computer dead').

Either your memory is not good or not fast enough (or too fast) or the socket is broken or the chip is not correctly in the socket or something like that.